# While in android layout edtior, Properties view does not get updated when i click any view

Tags: android, eclipse, layout, properties, editor

HI I have this weird issue.
I have the latest version of ADT (11) in eclipse 3.6 R2. 
When i open any layout xml in graphical view and if i click on any component, the properties window does not get updated/refreshed.

Does any one have face this before? Any solutions?

Note: i Have this issue in some previous verion of ADT as well. Also i use google plugin installed.

I have a seperate copy of eclipse + ADT which works well. (ADT version 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Eclipse 3.6.2 (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=162079 ) - if you use an earlier version (e.g. 3.5.2) or a 3.7 milestone it should work.

However, we've fixed this for ADT 12 such that it should work on all Eclipse versions (see http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17384 ).

-- Tor

Comment: i installed ADT 11 on ecipse 3.7 M4, now it doesnt even show graphical layout :( i get error saying "No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document."

Comment: Do you by any chance have a GestureOverlayView as the root child of your layout? If so, that can explain a bug which was fixed in ADT 12 (which was released yesterday).  If not, I suspect there's some error/exception thrown that causes this. Can you look in your Error Log? Here's the details on the GestureOverlayView bug: https://review.source.android.com//#/c/23656/   By the way, sorry it took me so long to answer this -- I don't log into stackoverflow often so I just saw this now. You're better off filing bugs on b.android.com :)

Comment: no issues. thanks a lot. infact my problem got fixed in eclipse 3.7 final release with latest ADT and it worked. :)